# How can I resolve ModuleNotFound Error in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a Django project for some time now. However, I am unable to resolve this error when I start the development server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/chanakgautam/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraper_app'
```

Based off previous posts I've read, I suspected the issue could lie in my file structuring. But my structure (below) appears to be alright.

```
djangoProject [**scraper**]
├── djangoProject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── *scraper_app*
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── templates
│   ├── results.html
│   └── search.html
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

The scraper_app directory has all the necessary files, so that is not an issue. Any help will be appreciated...

Installed apps:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # other apps
    'scraper_app',
]
```

I am trying to import scraper_app in the manage.py file

Comment: Where are you importing `scraper_app`?

Comment: Post your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Your `scraper_app` looks like an empty folder (or a file without extension).